# Why am I getting characters changing in my replace to �?

Tags: vb.net, unicode, ascii

I have hundreds of text files with thousands of records in each. See sample record below.

> 3”100”56”2016-10-26 03:00:52.107”2016-10-26 07:00:52.000”1509”1”1509”17”1”-21749”-23437”0”2”0”0”0”0”0”0”1”1”80.844208”2”1”0.51136178”3”1”0.4092806”4”1”638”5”1”0”6”1”0”7”1”7”8”1”3”9”1”914”10”1”984”11”1”1094”12”1”817”13”1”1246”14”1”583”15”1”89”16”1”233”17”1”771”18”1”405”19”1”245”20”1”528”21”1”325”0”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL”NULL

These were an export done from SQL that I did not set up.

I am changing the `NULL` text to `""` so that it is truly NULL. Once data has been corrected I am running a bulk insert.

Here is a copy of my Find/Replace code.

```
Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(LBRQFileName).Replace("NULL", "")
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(LBRQFileName, fileReader, False)
```

This code works great if the delimiter is '`,`' or '`;`' or anything normal.
However, a lot of these files have a `”` character (U+201D : RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK {double comma quotation mark}) as the delimiter. In this situation, when I run the find and replace for NULL I end up with something like this (Small example):

```
1�245�20�1�528�21�1�325�0��������������
```

(several in a row where "Null" was the value)

I have tried running a find and replace on that double quote, only to have same results. I have tried coming up with ways of setting up the delimiter as the RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK(Works in SSMS, but not from VB).

Running the replace for both the RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK and "NULL" from notepad......works fine.....

But I have hundreds of files to do. I don't have time to open each one up in notepad.

Update:

Changed code to Read and Write in ASCII. After I ran the replaced code, I was left with a usable delimiter.

```
Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(LBRQFileName, Encoding.ASCII).Replace("NULL", "")
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(LBRQFileName, fileReader, False, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
```

Comment: You'll have to go slower, it is ReadAllText() that produces this glyph, not Replace().  It will assume the file is encoded in utf8, looks like it wasn't.  Encoding.Default ought to be the next guess.  If that doesn't pan out either then you need to update your SO profile so we can tell where you live and use a hex viewer so we know what the character code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because those are right quotes quotes... you need to change the text file encoding

```
 Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(LBRQFileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8).Replace("NULL", "")

 My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(LBRQFileName, fileReader, False, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
```

Default vb.net text files do not support that character.

Comment: Maybe I have been staring at this for to long, to which left quotes are you referring? Tried your change of code and got, 1�245�20�1�528�21�1�325�0�������

Comment: .Net writes UTF-8 by default, not ASCII.

Comment: That is a LEFT quote ---> ”NULL

Comment: I am sorry, but that is right double quotation mark. https://unicodelookup.com/#”/1

Comment: Whatever, you need to figure out what the original encoding was, read it in that format and write it back in the same format.

Comment: See my edit.. I copied your text to a file and tested it with that code and got the expected results.... though your source text files may use a different encoding. Open one of the source files in notepad and click save as and see what encoding is listed at the bottom in the dropdown.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions @Trevor, made changes to  Read and Write encoding and solved my issue. I will update my Question with the new code.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve the same thing Using System.IO Library

```
    Using str As New IO.StreamReader("C:\1.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, True)

        strText = str.ReadToEnd.Replace("NULL", "")
        str.Close()

    End Using

    Using stw As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\1.txt", False, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)

        stw.Write(strText)
        stw.Close()

    End Using
```

It works fine for me